# read multiple text files and count the occurances of a word?

Tags: c++

I am supposed to read(scan) data from a folder with multiple(21578) text files, and file names are numbered from  1 to 21578,and read each word that occurs in a text file, and count the number of times it occurs in the entire folder,i.e; in all the files
how do i go about it?
Plz help.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    using namespace std;

    void main ()
    {
    string STRING;
ifstream infile;
for(int i=0;i<21578;i++)
    {


infile.open (i+".txt");
    while(!infile.eof) // To get you all the lines.
    {
        getline(infile,STRING); // Saves the line in STRING.
        cout<<STRING; // Prints our STRING.
    }
infile.close();
system ("pause");
    }
    }
```

Comment: Also, you don't need to use getline.  while(infile>>someString) is much easier.  I added a little code to demo for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to create a map of strings to ints.

```
std::map<std::string, int>
```

And then increment the containing int, or add to the map if it doesn't exist.

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/

If you're using c++11(I think) or later, you can even use unordered_map, which instead of using sorting to access elements uses hashing.  This is an optimization you could look into, if performance matters.

Here's some sample code to get you started

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void incrementString(map<string, int> &theMap, string &theString) {
    if(theMap.count(theString)) {
        theMap[theString]++;
    } else {
        theMap[theString] = 1;//This fixes the issue the other poster mentioned, though on most systems is not necessary, and this function would not need an if/else block at all.
    }
}

void printMap(map<string, int> &theMap) {
    map<string, int>::iterator it = theMap.begin();

    do {
        cout << it->first << ": " << it->second << endl;
    } while(++it != theMap.end());

}

int main() {
    map<string, int> stringMap;

    string hi = "hi";//Assigning "hi" to a string, like like cin>>string would.
    string the = "the";

    incrementString(stringMap, hi);//Adding one occurance of hi to the map

    incrementString(stringMap, the);//Adding one occurance of the to the map

    incrementString(stringMap, hi);//Adding another occurance of hi to the map

    printMap(stringMap); //Printing the map so far
}

int main_alt() {
    map<string, int> stringMap;

    string someString;

    while(cin>>someString) {//reads string from std::cin, I recommend using this instead of getline()
        incrementString(stringMap, someString);
    }

    printMap(stringMap);
}
```

The expected output is thus:

```
hi: 2
the: 1
```

Also, if you enebale "main_alt()" you can call your program like this and see how the while(cin>>string) line works.

```
./program < someFile.txt
```

Comment: Hi!thanks so much, but i don't quite get as to what's going on in the main() fn, could you please explain?

Comment: I'm demoing how to use the functions I provided.  I will comment.  This isn't meant to be a solution.  Adding my functions to your loops should be trivial.

Answer (score 0):

When reading all files in the directory, you are much better off doing that using the OS facilities instead of making assumptions on what the filenames are (unless those are more or less guaranteed.) So, I'd suggest using `opendir` and `readdir` in POSIX-compliant systems and similar facilities in Windows.

Now, when counting the occurrences, you'd naturally resort to a `std::map<string, int>` in the following fashion:

```
// collect

for (all files) {
    open fin;

    while (fin >> str)
        mymap[str]++;   // will create an entry if not here with a default value of 0

}

// print counts

for (map<string,int>::iterator it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it)
    cout << it->first << "  :  " << it->second << std::endl;
```